# Create a workflow populating a field on isnew()

Tags: workflow, new

I am trying to populate a field on a junction object every time a new instance of the junction object is created. This is my first time using workflows and I'm a little confused.

What I used for the rule criteria is:

```
 Rule Criteria: ISNEW()
```

As for the **Immediate Workflow Actions** I have chosen a "field update" and then linked to the field of the junction object. In **Specify New Field Value** I have chosen formula and entered "hello". The field is of a type text.

Next when I create a new junction object that text field is not populated with the "hello" value. It remains empty. What am I not doing right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to workflow so I am providing screen shots follow them,hope this help also don't forget to "Activate" the workflow :

[image]

For Field update:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I believe my issue was that I had not pressed on the activate button since I did not see it at first. Your screenshots really helped though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ISNEW(), check the box under `Evaluation Criteria` that says `Created` and change Rule Criteria: `{!Object}:Created Date` not equal to `null`.